# How to save cipher text to db if it has illegal characters?

Tags: mysql, ruby, encryption

I am working on encrypting text strings that contain sensitive data. I need to save these encrypted strings to a MySQL db. The strings are cipher text, and all character (printable ASCII to control characters to `null` are equally likely).

These strings are not long (< 40 characters). I am using Ruby 2.1 (no Rails) along with the encryptor gem with a custom salt and iv to do the encryption. The encryptor gem is a wrapper for Ruby's openssl.

For many strings this works fine. However, I have run into a small number of these strings that, once encrypted, contain illegal or improperly quoted characters. As a result, when the string is saved I get an error.

What is the best way to handle the encrypted value so it can be reliably saved to MySQL?

Here is my encryption command:

```
require 'encryptor'
encrypted_value = Encryptor.encrypt(@sensitive_string, 
:key => @config["encryption"]["key"], 
:iv = @config["encryption"]["iv"], 
:salt => @config["encryption"]["salt"])
```

Here is the encrypted value:

```
encrypted_value: /:Z`߉Nc??"v'??\??؟??????Oa?jR
```

and a screenshot since some of the characters did not copy correctly: 
[image]

MySQL update statement:

```
query = "UPDATE db.table  
SET `key` = mysql_real_escape_string(#{encrypted_value})"
```

With the value in the query it looks like:

```
query UPDATE db.table 
             SET `key` = mysql_real_escape_string(/:Z`߉Nc??"v'??\??؟??????Oa?jR)
```

I have tried both the MySQL Quote and mysql_real_escape_string functions. I get the same error with both and also wrapping the encrypted_value in double and single quotes.

Then I get this error:

```
wrong number of arguments (0 for 2) (ArgumentError)
```

What is the best way to tackle this? Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: As a side note: The point of IV/salt is to be different for each encryption. So reading them from the configuration misses the point.

Comment: You usually do one of two things: (1) use a [binary `BLOB`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blob.html) to store the raw cipher text; or (2) encode the raw cipher text into printable ASCIIs with Hex, Base32, Base64, etc. Then store it like a string or `char*`. The binary BLOB is probably most efficient. Its most compact, and does not require the additional encoding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can perform base64 encoding of encrypted string, and store the encoded value in DB.

When retrieving the value, you can decode it back to binary and decrypt it.

```
require "base64"

enc   = Base64.encode64('Send reinforcements')
                    # -> "U2VuZCByZWluZm9yY2VtZW50cw==\n"
plain = Base64.decode64(enc)
                    # -> "Send reinforcements"
```

http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.0/libdoc/base64/rdoc/Base64.html